# Magento API order not returning order 'custom options'

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using the https://myhost/api/rest/orders JSON endpoint to get orders information.

The problem I'm having is the 'custom options' the user chooses when adding a product to the cart isn't showing up in this returned data.

Custom options is a feature that ships by default with Magento 1.7 but can't get the data out.

Looking in the admin console and going to the product page > 'custom options' (as below) 
[image]

Then going to the actual order page, there's no refernce to the SKU, nor the added price amount.

Makes me wonder why there is an SKU field in the first place. Any help appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using custom options on simple products what should be a configurable product?